# How can I "make" a pdf file from a php file?

Tags: php, pdf, header

Lets say I have the following file:

layout.php

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<table width="700" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Nombre</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo $_SESSION['id']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $_SESSION['nombre']; ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Is there a way where I can download that file as a PDF that will output the file like you see it in the browser?

I tried this but it didnt work:

```
<?php
session_start();

header("Content-type:application/pdf");
header("Content-Disposition:attachment;filename=info_user.pdf");
readfile('layout.php');
?>
```

Comment: PDF files are in a specific format, you can't just make one like that.  You need to use a library like [dompdf](https://code.google.com/p/dompdf/) or [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/).

Comment: No, there's no way to do so, for the same reason that you can't just send `Content-Type: audio/mpeg3` and get a song.

Answer (score 3):

There are several packages that allow you to generate PDF files. You can have a look at these:

- [PHP's PDF Class](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdf.php)
- [FPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)
- [TCPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)

Answer (score 1):

The PDFlib library of PHP is probably the most developed library for this.

You can read about them [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdf.php) on PHP dev.

Other alternate libraries include:

- [tcPDF](http://www.tcpdf.org/)
- [fPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/)
- [Zend_PDF](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.pdf.html)

Answer (score 0):

Chrome can save a web page to PDF, if that helps you.